# Destructuring a variadic function with an as-binding: not possible?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

Until now, I had always assumed that anything you can do in `let` binding, you can do within the arguments vector for a `defn` form.

However, I just noticed this -- if I do this with a `let` binding, it works:

```
(let [[x & more :as full-list] (range 10)]
  (println "x:" x) 
  (println "more:" more) 
  (println "full list:" full-list))

; x: 0 
; more: (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) 
; full list: (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

But if I try to pull it out into a function, I get an exception:

```
(defn foo [x & more :as full-list]
  (println "x:" x) 
  (println "more:" more) 
  (println "full list:" full-list))

; CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected parameter, compiling:(/tmp/form-init615613631940782255.clj:1:1)
```

Of note, this works:

```
(defn foo [[x & more :as full-list]]
  (println "x:" x) 
  (println "more:" more) 
  (println "full list:" full-list))
```

But then I have to pass in the argument as a collection, i.e. `(foo [1 2 3])`.

Is it possible to define a function that takes a variable number of arguments, and bind the entire group of arguments to a local variable, without specifically using a `let` binding inside? It strikes me as weird that you can't just do `(defn foo [x & more :as full-list] ...` Is there a particular reason why this doesn't (or shouldn't) work?

Comment: +1 I ran into this myself recently and am pretty frustrated by it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a variable number of args, you are missing an &:

```
(defn foo [& [x & more :as full-list]]
  (println "x:" x) 
  (println "more:" more) 
  (println "full list:" full-list))
```

Clojure param definition has only one special case that is the `&` char to indicate a variadic number of arguments. The rest are plain simple named arguments.

Now each simple argument can be destructured using the map or list syntax. For example:

```
(defn foo [ x y ] ...)
```

Can be destructured like:

```
(defn foo [[x1 x2 & x-more :as x] {:keys [y1 y2 y3]}] ...)
```

So we are saying that we expect the first param to be a list of at least 2 elements and the second param to be a map with some keys. Note that this will still be a fn of two params and that Clojure is not going to enforce that x actually has at least two elements. If x is an empty list, x1 and x2 will be nil.

Coming back to your question, if you look at my answer you will see that my fn has 0 mandatory params, with a variable number of arguments, while the one that you have has 1 mandatory param with a a variable number of arguments. What I am doing is just destructuring the var arg.

Comment: That works - thanks! It's interesting that you have to add the first `&` only when you want to use the `:as` form... Doing `(defn foo [x & more] ...` works fine, but as soon as you add the `:as` part, you have to add the initial `&` to make it clear that the function is variadic. I wonder why that is?

Comment: I have updated the response with a longer explanation. Let me know if it makes more sense now

Comment: That makes it extra clear, thanks -- I just had a little "a-ha" moment. I guess a key difference between the way that `let`'s bindings work vs. the way `defn`'s bindings work is that `let` is expecting at least one thing to be bound to a local variable, whereas a function can take 0 arguments. With that difference in mind, it makes more sense to require an additional `&` on the front end of the binding to indicate that the function could possibly take 0 args.